# How to use Semantic-ui Sass and grunt together?

Tags: angularjs

I have to use Semantic-UI, SASS and grunt in my angular js project.Is it possible to do semantic-ui with sass .I am new in angular please someone suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantic-UI is written in LESS, so if you're looking to extend it, you won't be able to do it with SASS, but if you are simply looking to use it and supplement it with your own stylesheets, you can write those in SASS if you want.

Angular and Grunt don't come into this at all. Angular is an application framework and Grunt is a build tool, so they don't have a great deal to do with what CSS libraries you choose.

Comment: hlo thanks for answering  I am tring to use sass in my project I have installed ruby also but still not able to use to will you please help me

Comment: To use Sass, you need to install Ruby, then add the Ruby binary folder to your PATH, and install Sass with `gem install sass`. If you want to use Ruby Sass with Grunt, you'll need to run `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`. Libsass is actually pretty good now, so if you plan to write with the SCSS flavour, you can use `npm install grunt-sass --save-dev` and save yourself the trouble of working with Ruby.

Comment: Hii I am using scout for compilation of sass but getting argument related error. Is is okay to use scout ? please suggest me and thanks for your great help

Comment: I've never used Scout, and you shouldn't need to if you're using Grunt. It is a Sass compiler though, so it should work. If you're getting an argument error, you're probably using it incorrectly, so you should read up on usage

Comment: As I am using yeoman generator and its automatically generating grunt.js for me so will you please give me idea how to use sass in yeoman angular generator grunt.js file.Thanks for your great Support

Comment: I am in great confusion sir .By default semantic is in LESS??? Please make me clear so that I use it in my project.

Comment: Semantic is written in LESS. That means you can't extend it with Sass, but you can still take the compiled CSS files and use them.